# I can't take image from opengl screen

Tags: c#, opengl

```
OpenGLWindow(); 
opl = new OpenGLWindow();
opl.Parent = panel1;
opl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
opl.Refresh();
```

here the code. I can take picture of panel1 but I can't take openGL picture. The question is: how can I take OpenGL screenshot

```
var frm = Panel1;
using (var bmp = new Bitmap(frm.Width, frm.Height))
{
    frm.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
    bmp.Save(@"c:\screenshot.Jpeg");
}
```

Comment: Is this code really in C#, C++, and C?  It looks like pure C#.

Comment: Yes, this code is C# with using OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly who OpenGLWindow is, but i assume you use some framework, some C# wrapper over the OpenGL API. If that is the case, most probably the OpenGL renders directly to the video memory which is not accessible for GDI, thaht's why you probably get an empty image.

To actually get the image rendered by OpenGL, you need to call [glReadPixels](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml). Your framework might expose to you a wrapper method over this glReadPixels or I believe you can directly call glReadPixels via pinvoke, with the appropriate parameters and obtain the image you want (it might be upside down and with the red and blue channels inversed, but you will be able to fix these issues by manipulating the byte array).

Comment: OpenGLWindow is My OpenGL Class. i wrote all opengl controls in OpenGLWindow. after that i used in form.

Comment: Ok, then it means you have access to OpenGL api and you can simply call glReadPixels :)